# DateTime and Databinding in WPF - Leading zeros and blank label

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I have a WPF label bound to a DateTime and I need it to start at 1/1/1. When it is set to 1/1/1, the label does not appear at all. If I change any of the numbers, it displays leading zeros in front of the year (1/2/0001). All of this worked fine before when I was using WinForms.

Does anybody know how to have the label display when set to 1/1/1 and/or how to do away with the leading zeros?

Also, since I'm looking to use fictional times, are there any other methods I could try that might be more suitable?

```
DateTime _date = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);

public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set
        {
            if (_date != value)
            {
                _date = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Date);
            }
        }
    }
```

From my XAML

```
Label Content="{Binding Date}" Style="{DynamicResource SimpleLabel}" FontFamily="Pericles" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/
```

Comment: Could you post some of the data-binding code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=\{0:d\/M\/y\}}" />
<Label Content="{Binding Date}"
        ContentStringFormat="{}{0:d\/M\/y}" />
```

Works fine for me. Remember `ContentStringFormat` for `Label`

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom ['IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) class that formats the dates the way you want them formatted.